# How to set proper paper margins?

Tags: margins, geometry

I am trying to send a paper to a conference with specific margin requirements. I use the geometry package to define the margins.

```
\usepackage[papersize={8.5in,11in}, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

However, I still get errors when trying to upload. e.g, The paper has a bottom margin of 0.958 inches on page 3, which does not leave 1 inches of margin.

Why are the margins set by geometry getting overridden? Is there a way to hard set the margins if so?

Thank You in advance !

Comment: Use the `showframe` option for `geometry` package and then you can see what happens on every page. Also, you can just use `margin=1in`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Do you need to add `includeall` so that headers, footers, margin notes etc. are all put within the area allowed for the text body? In addition to `showframe`, you can pass `verbose` to get console output showing the results of `geometry`'s calculations.

Comment: How do you know the bottom of p3 has a margin of 0.958"? Is this calculated automatically through some submission system?

Comment: @Werner Yes. Calculated by edas.info

Comment: It is possible to push past the bottom margin, for example a full page figure which is too big.  You should get a warning.

Comment: @Andy do you use `\documentclass` option for paper size?

Comment: @juanquispe Yes I use, **\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}** which I guess defaults to an a4 sized paper

Comment: @Andy well, a4 paper size is 8.3 in x 11.7 in, I don't know if it is against the papersize option of geometry package.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. Using `includeall` as suggested by @cfr worked for me at the time. Thank You everyone for the help.

Comment: @juanuni It was mentioned in the requirements to use 8.5in by 11in size.